# Access via network without password

Tags: windows, samba, password

Have set-up Samba and gotten connected to my Ubuntu box from Windows network, but now playing up with password and cannot connect again :(. I really need to get my data across to Ubuntu box so I can use it as main PC instead of an ornament. Data is currently scattered over several Win pcs

I really do not want the bother of a password as I need to be able to use all my computers as a unit. So how do I get rid of the need for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dolphin makes it simple to connect to Windows and no need for passwords.